# How to access (read/write) workspace variables from within S-function code?

Tags: matlab, simulink

Is it possible to access workspace variables from within S-function code?

Below are tested variants which are not working. There is a `MyVar` variable in `Model Workspace`, which is visible from `Model Explorer`. Lines are runned from within `DoPostPropSetup` function of custom block code.

Appropriate error messages are in post comments

```
% a=evalin('Model Workspace', 'MyVar'); % Unknown command option.
% a=evalin('caller', 'MyVar'); % (incorrect workspace)
% a=Simulink.MyVar % Undefined variable "Simulink" or class "Simulink.MyVar".
% a=simulink.MyVar; % Undefined variable "simulink" or class "simulink.MyVar".
% a=Simulink.ModelWorkspace.evalin('MyVar'); % has no property or method named 'evalin'.
```

Latter is direct violation of documented facts: http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.modelworkspace.html

**UPDATE**

Found something new

```
 % a=evalin('modelworkspace', 'MyVar'); % Unknown command option.

   hws = get_param(bdroot, 'modelworkspace');
%   a = hws.evalin('MyVar'); % Attempt to evaluate an expression in a read-only model workspace

   a = hws.getVariable('MyVar'); % works
```

latter command works, but (1) previous command said that workspace is "read only", while I need to write to variable too.

And (2) [`bdroot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/bdroot.html?searchHighlight=bdroot) function is documented as returning "name of top-level Simulink system", which is totally unclear. I need to access workspace (not it's name) of the model, where current code' block resided.

Comment: Have you tried `gcs` instead of `bdroot`?

Comment: I already found `gcb` and was taking it's parent and in other block methods `evalin` was read-write. Thanks for `gcs`!